# Accidently deleted Downloads folder

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I was trying to permanently delete a file when I accidently used shift+delete on the Downloads folder.

Now I can't restore it.

I can see the folder in my Users directory but i keep getting access denied errors, and 
I've tried to change ownership of the folder to myself, but I can't (I'm a local admin on the box)

Does anyone know what I can do here?

Comment: You won't be able to restore it unless you use an entirely different user.

Comment: this is possible. i can ccreate another local admin user but not clear on what to do. can you help elaborate? 
also i don't care so much for the files in the folder as i just need the folder to work as expected again.

Comment: Creating `<X>:\Users\<username>\Downloads` does not help?

Comment: the problem is it already exists. I can't delete the existing one, access it or change ownership.

Comment: Maybe try this: http://scottiestech.info/2014/11/11/repair-missing-user-folders-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the link from @FlashThunder I got the bright idea that maybe windows was holding on to the handle/reference to the folder in memory.

So I rebooted the machine and sure enough the folder disappeared. 
After that, it was just a matter of

- recreating folder
- rebooting
- reapplying attributes (2nd to last step in link)
- rebooting again

all good now.

Thanks everyone.

for the lazy, here is the link:
http://scottiestech.info/2014/11/11/repair-missing-user-folders-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running as an "admin" in Explorer, go the the next folder up, that the download folder resided in.   The folder you want is likely:
C:
\Users
[logged in username]

1. Highlight that folder,
2. right click that folder,
3. and go to the tab: Previous Versions.

You should at least see a snapshot from the last time and date you rebooted or did a Windows update.  Choose the earliest date. I'd suggest opening that snapshot in a new Explorer window, and then copying back whatever you want, manually.

Comment: thank you for trying. unfortunately. http://imgur.com/heY7Ex0

Comment: Wow, that's unfortunate that you don't have any active snapshots.  Although it might not help right now, I'd strongly suggest you figure out why, and then fix your PC to start taking snapshots.  Hopefully, you have some source of a backup. If not, you should check your browser's download history.  You might at least be able to find what you downloaded, and re-download as needed.